# How can I order a queryset by a filtered bridge table field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Given the following models

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Follow')

class Follow(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

If I have a user, how can I get blogs the user follows, ordered by the date they started following them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
qs = user.blog_set.all().order_by("follow__created")
```

For descending order use the following:

```
qs = user.blog_set.all().order_by("-follow__created")
```

I am not sure about "order_by" part, but you can "play" with it.

Comment: [Django docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api): `order_by("-follow__created")`

Comment: Turns out I had it right 9 out of the 10 things I tried, and this works fine. I was using a DateField rather then a DateTimeField, and not seeing it put newly created objects first...